# initialization vectors in CBC mode encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography

what is the purpose of initialization vectors in CBC mode encryption?

Comment: Did you read Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I think he prefers our personalized service.

Answer (score 2):

For a given plaintext input and a key, the IV is used to ensure the ciphertext is different each time the plaintext is encrypted with the key.